# HTC Desire randomly wakes up

Tags: 2.2-froyo, htc-desire, car-dock

I have an HTC desire, which switches on randomly. To get to the source of the problem, I waited for the phone to wake up (screen turned on), then grabbed the system log and mailed it to myself. <del>These are the last few seconds, from when the screen turned on:</del> EDIT: on request, I included from the log, about 8 minutes:

```
10-22 15:20:34.111 D/dalvikvm(  566): GC_EXPLICIT freed 3609 objects / 197928 bytes in 104ms
10-22 15:20:40.287 D/dalvikvm(  456): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1971 objects / 170600 bytes in 92ms
10-22 15:20:45.807 D/dalvikvm( 4668): GC_EXPLICIT freed 11540 objects / 845064 bytes in 93ms
10-22 15:20:50.817 D/dalvikvm(  251): GC_EXPLICIT freed 3563 objects / 228536 bytes in 82ms
10-22 15:20:50.817 D/NativeCrypto(  251): Freeing OpenSSL session
10-22 15:20:55.797 D/dalvikvm( 4315): GC_EXPLICIT freed 2928 objects / 165840 bytes in 68ms
10-22 15:21:05.724 D/dalvikvm( 2488): GC_EXPLICIT freed 2030 objects / 76504 bytes in 250ms
10-22 15:21:47.999 V/AlarmManager(   92): Alarm triggering: Alarm{46875928 type 0 com.levelup.touiteur}
10-22 15:21:48.059 D/Plume_54205( 4668): No network connection found! interfaces:[NetworkInfo: type: mobile[UNKNOWN], state: UNKNOWN/IDLE, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, NetworkInfo: type: WIFI[], state: DISCONNECTED/DISCONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: false, if: eth0, NetworkInfo: type: mobile_mms[UNKNOWN], state: UNKNOWN/IDLE, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, NetworkInfo: type: mobile_supl[UNKNOWN], state: UNKNOWN/IDLE, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, NetworkInfo: type: mobile_dun[UNKNOWN], state: UNKNOWN/IDLE, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, NetworkInfo: type: mobile_hipri[UNKNOWN], state: UNKNOWN/IDLE, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, NetworkInfo: type: mobile_wapgateway[UNKNOWN], state: UNKNOWN/IDLE, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, NetworkInfo: type: mobile_httpproxy[UNKNOWN], state: UNKNOWN/IDLE, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, NetworkInfo: type: mobile_fota[UNKNOWN], state: UNKNOWN/IDLE, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, NetworkInfo: type: mobile_admin[UNKNOWN], state: UNKNOWN/IDLE, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, NetworkInfo: type: mobile_internet[UNKNOWN], state: UNKNOWN/IDLE, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, NetworkInfo: type: mobile_mobilemarket[UNKNOWN], state: UNKNOWN/IDLE, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true]
10-22 15:21:48.059 V/Plume_54205( 4668): start the outbox service in 2 minutes
10-22 15:21:48.059 V/AlarmManager(   92): Adding Alarm{46578f40 type 0 com.levelup.touiteur} okt. 22 03:23:48 PM
10-22 15:23:29.651 D/HtcLockScreen(   92): onRefreshBatteryInfo showBatteryInfo:truepluggedIn:falsebatteryLevel:11
10-22 15:23:29.651 D/HtcLockScreen(   92): onRefreshBatteryInfo currentData mPluggedIn:falsemBatteryLevel:12
10-22 15:23:29.651 I/HtcLockScreen(   92): updateStatusViewByPriority, mIsSimCheckView = false, mIsBatteryInfo = true, mIsMusicPlaying = false, mIsAirPlaneMode = false
10-22 15:23:29.691 I/global  (   92): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
10-22 15:23:29.691 I/global  (   92): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
10-22 15:23:29.691 D/BatteryService(   92): isUsbConnected() = false
10-22 15:23:29.691 D/BatteryService(   92): mPlugType = 0
10-22 15:23:29.721 E/Tethering(   92): attempting to remove unknown iface (usb0), ignoring
10-22 15:23:29.721 D/UsbConnectedReceiver( 2308): action = psclient.intent.action.usb_status
10-22 15:23:29.721 D/UsbConnectedReceiver( 2308): ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED
10-22 15:23:29.721 D/UsbConnectedReceiver( 2308): usbCurrentType = 0
10-22 15:23:29.721 D/UsbConnectedReceiver( 2308): Current type is same as previous, return!
10-22 15:23:47.999 V/AlarmManager(   92): Alarm triggering: Alarm{46578f40 type 0 com.levelup.touiteur}
10-22 15:23:48.057 D/Plume_54205( 4668): No network connection found! interfaces:[NetworkInfo: type: mobile[UNKNOWN], state: UNKNOWN/IDLE, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, NetworkInfo: type: WIFI[], state: DISCONNECTED/DISCONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: false, if: eth0, NetworkInfo: type: mobile_mms[UNKNOWN], state: UNKNOWN/IDLE, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, NetworkInfo: type: mobile_supl[UNKNOWN], state: UNKNOWN/IDLE, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, NetworkInfo: type: mobile_dun[UNKNOWN], state: UNKNOWN/IDLE, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, NetworkInfo: type: mobile_hipri[UNKNOWN], state: UNKNOWN/IDLE, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, NetworkInfo: type: mobile_wapgateway[UNKNOWN], state: UNKNOWN/IDLE, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, NetworkInfo: type: mobile_httpproxy[UNKNOWN], state: UNKNOWN/IDLE, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, NetworkInfo: type: mobile_fota[UNKNOWN], state: UNKNOWN/IDLE, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, NetworkInfo: type: mobile_admin[UNKNOWN], state: UNKNOWN/IDLE, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, NetworkInfo: type: mobile_internet[UNKNOWN], state: UNKNOWN/IDLE, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, NetworkInfo: type: mobile_mobilemarket[UNKNOWN], state: UNKNOWN/IDLE, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true]
10-22 15:23:48.057 V/Plume_54205( 4668): start the outbox service in 2 minutes
10-22 15:23:48.057 V/AlarmManager(   92): Adding Alarm{468dc160 type 0 com.levelup.touiteur} okt. 22 03:25:48 PM
10-22 15:24:11.092 D/dalvikvm(  566): GC_EXPLICIT freed 962 objects / 59664 bytes in 37ms
10-22 15:24:21.543 D/dalvikvm( 4668): GC_EXPLICIT freed 8216 objects / 559912 bytes in 305ms
10-22 15:25:47.999 V/AlarmManager(   92): Alarm triggering: Alarm{468dc160 type 0 com.levelup.touiteur}
10-22 15:25:48.044 D/Plume_54205( 4668): No network connection found! interfaces:[NetworkInfo: type: mobile[UNKNOWN], state: UNKNOWN/IDLE, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, NetworkInfo: type: WIFI[], state: DISCONNECTED/DISCONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: false, if: eth0, NetworkInfo: type: mobile_mms[UNKNOWN], state: UNKNOWN/IDLE, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, NetworkInfo: type: mobile_supl[UNKNOWN], state: UNKNOWN/IDLE, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, NetworkInfo: type: mobile_dun[UNKNOWN], state: UNKNOWN/IDLE, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, NetworkInfo: type: mobile_hipri[UNKNOWN], state: UNKNOWN/IDLE, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, NetworkInfo: type: mobile_wapgateway[UNKNOWN], state: UNKNOWN/IDLE, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, NetworkInfo: type: mobile_httpproxy[UNKNOWN], state: UNKNOWN/IDLE, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, NetworkInfo: type: mobile_fota[UNKNOWN], state: UNKNOWN/IDLE, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, NetworkInfo: type: mobile_admin[UNKNOWN], state: UNKNOWN/IDLE, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, NetworkInfo: type: mobile_internet[UNKNOWN], state: UNKNOWN/IDLE, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, NetworkInfo: type: mobile_mobilemarket[UNKNOWN], state: UNKNOWN/IDLE, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true]
10-22 15:25:48.054 V/Plume_54205( 4668): start the outbox service in 2 minutes
10-22 15:25:48.054 V/AlarmManager(   92): Adding Alarm{467017a8 type 0 com.levelup.touiteur} okt. 22 03:27:48 PM
10-22 15:27:48.000 V/AlarmManager(   92): Alarm triggering: Alarm{467017a8 type 0 com.levelup.touiteur}
10-22 15:27:48.058 D/Plume_54205( 4668): No network connection found! interfaces:[NetworkInfo: type: mobile[UNKNOWN], state: UNKNOWN/IDLE, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, NetworkInfo: type: WIFI[], state: DISCONNECTED/DISCONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: false, if: eth0, NetworkInfo: type: mobile_mms[UNKNOWN], state: UNKNOWN/IDLE, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, NetworkInfo: type: mobile_supl[UNKNOWN], state: UNKNOWN/IDLE, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, NetworkInfo: type: mobile_dun[UNKNOWN], state: UNKNOWN/IDLE, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, NetworkInfo: type: mobile_hipri[UNKNOWN], state: UNKNOWN/IDLE, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, NetworkInfo: type: mobile_wapgateway[UNKNOWN], state: UNKNOWN/IDLE, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, NetworkInfo: type: mobile_httpproxy[UNKNOWN], state: UNKNOWN/IDLE, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, NetworkInfo: type: mobile_fota[UNKNOWN], state: UNKNOWN/IDLE, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, NetworkInfo: type: mobile_admin[UNKNOWN], state: UNKNOWN/IDLE, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, NetworkInfo: type: mobile_internet[UNKNOWN], state: UNKNOWN/IDLE, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, NetworkInfo: type: mobile_mobilemarket[UNKNOWN], state: UNKNOWN/IDLE, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true]
10-22 15:27:48.058 V/Plume_54205( 4668): start the outbox service in 2 minutes
10-22 15:27:48.058 V/AlarmManager(   92): Adding Alarm{46910018 type 0 com.levelup.touiteur} okt. 22 03:29:48 PM
10-22 15:28:15.453 D/dalvikvm(  566): GC_EXPLICIT freed 3 objects / 72 bytes in 39ms
10-22 15:28:39.586 W/Vold    (   62): Ignoring unknown switch 'dock'
10-22 15:28:39.596 I/power   (   92): *** set_screen_state 1
10-22 15:28:39.606 I/HtcLockScreen(   92): HtcLockScreen:onResume
10-22 15:28:39.606 D/AK8973  (   72): Compass Start
10-22 15:28:39.606 D/Sensors (   92): open_akm, fd=124
10-22 15:28:39.616 D/BluetoothService(   92): FileNotFoundException while trying to read dock address
10-22 15:28:39.616 I/DockObserver(   92): Dock state changed: 0
10-22 15:28:39.736 D/Sensors (   92): close_akm, fd=124
10-22 15:28:39.736 V/BluetoothService(   92): Received ACTION_DOCK_EVENT with State:0
10-22 15:28:39.746 D/SurfaceFlinger(   92): Screen about to return, flinger = 0x15bc38
10-22 15:28:39.766 D/ConnectivityService(   92): getMobileDataEnabled returning false
10-22 15:28:39.786 D/ConnectivityService(   92): getMobileDataEnabled returning false
10-22 15:28:39.786 D/ConnectivityService(   92): getMobileDataEnabled returning false
10-22 15:28:39.846 D/browser ( 4164): screen intent received: android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON
10-22 15:28:39.846 D/browser ( 4164): mActivityInPause=true toggleAutorestart=true
10-22 15:28:39.846 D/browser ( 4164): restartFlag=false restartPowerLock=WakeLock{46355778 held=false, refCount=0}
10-22 15:28:40.266 D/AK8973  (   72): Compass CLOSE
10-22 15:28:40.306 W/Vold    (   62): Ignoring unknown switch 'dock'
10-22 15:28:40.316 D/BluetoothService(   92): FileNotFoundException while trying to read dock address
10-22 15:28:40.316 I/DockObserver(   92): Dock state changed: 2
10-22 15:28:40.336 D/AK8973  (   72): Compass Start
10-22 15:28:40.336 D/Sensors (   92): open_akm, fd=124
10-22 15:28:40.346 V/BluetoothService(   92): Received ACTION_DOCK_EVENT with State:2
10-22 15:28:40.346 E/ApplicationContext(   92): Couldn't create directory for SharedPreferences file shared_prefs/bluetooth_service_settings.xml
10-22 15:28:40.696 D/PowerManagerService(   92): New lightsensor value:160, lcdValue:160
10-22 15:28:42.756 D/PowerManagerService(   92): New lightsensor value:90, lcdValue:160
10-22 15:28:43.179 I/HtcLockScreen(   92): touch ACTION_DOWN
10-22 15:28:43.179 I/HtcLockScreen(   92): stopPhoneAnimation
10-22 15:28:43.286 I/HtcLockScreen(   92): touch ACTION_UP
10-22 15:28:43.286 D/HtcLockScreen(   92): unlock a
```

My guess is that it thinks it is docked in a car dock, since I had trouble with the phone randomly going into car mode earlier (I switched off car mode to avoid that). The dock state changes twice in this log, once to 0 and once to 2. A value of 2 means it's in a car dock, and a value of 0 means it's undocked.

What is the cause of this problem? Is this something I can fix (or get fixed cheaply), or is it time to start looking for a new phone?

UPDATE: I am not connected to wifi, mobile data, bluetooth or anything.

Comment: Do you have a few more lines preceding the ones you posted? The 2nd line already is a reaction on the event in question (`set_screen_state 1` suggests the trigger already had occured, and the only preceding line is not really explaining things).

Comment: I also see a line near the middle of his paste that reads `screen intent received: android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON` and  `V/BluetoothService(   92): Received ACTION_DOCK_EVENT with State:0` and a few other Bluetooth/Dock messages immediately before `SCREEN_ON`. Daan, are you linked to any Bluetooth devices when this happens? Either way, I agree that more of the log may be helpful

Comment: Updated the question with more information: I extended the log to the last 10 minutes or so, and added information about wireless status (wifi, mobile data and bluetooth all off).